# Ruby on Rails: is there a standard helper for minimalistic implementing of create and update actions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, action

Is there in rails some standard helper method like this:

```
def standard_save model
  model_sym = model.class.name.underscore.to_sym

  model.update_attributes params[model_sym]
  if model.save
    yield
    redirect_to model
  else
    render :new
  end
  model
end
```

That you would use like this:

```
def create
  standard_save(@user = User.new) {
    flash[:success] = "You account was successfully created"
  }
end

def update
  standard_save @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

Answer (score 5):

There's the [inherited_resources](http://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources) gem you could use for this.